# What is the diffrence between following arduino boards and which should i buy?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

## Arduino UNO R3 Compatible Board ATmega328P ATmega16U2

http://www.ebay.in/itm/UNO-R3-ATmega328P-ATmega16U2-Compatible-Board-For-Arduino-with-USB-Cable-/201367107680?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item2ee26a3860

## Arduino UNO R3 ATmega328P USB Development Board CH340G

http://www.ebay.in/itm/UNO-R3-Development-Board-SMD-Chip-Arduino-Compatible-/301653217776?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item463beed1f0

#### I will be working on a windows 7 32 bit pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is an unofficial clone of an R3 using the same schematic as the real R3.  The second is a rough copy using a cheaper USB serial interface chip.

Neither of them are real Arduino boards.  The first one is closer to the real UNO and should do the same things that a real UNO should do (assuming it works at all).  The second one - well, who knows?  You certainly can't do any of the fancy things to the USB interface that you can with a real UNO R3.

Which should you buy? Well, really, you shouldn't buy either of them - but if you *must* go for one I'd pick the first one.  Better to buy a real UNO from Arduino though, at least then you know what it is you're getting, and you expect it to work.  With these cheap Chinese clones (Chinduinos) you may just get a bunch of counterfeit chips selotaped to a piece of cardboard.

Comment: You can't say 'selotape' anymore. The politically correct term is "sticky tape and promises".